# C++ - specialize function template on a templated class with a non type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I have a class template Foo:

```
template <class A, A value, class B>
class Foo {};
```

And I have a function template validateType()

```
template <class T>
bool validateType() {
    return false;
}
```

Now I want to specialize it for some types, including Foo, so that the function performs some static_asserts during compile time. I tried this:

```
template <class A, class B, Foo<A, A val, B>>
bool validateType() {
    // do some static asserts
}
```

and this:

```
template <class A, A val, class B>
bool validateType<Foo<A, val, B>>() {
    // do some static asserts
}
```

In the first one, the compiler says:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 3)
 template <class A, class B, Foo<A, A val, B>>
                                            ^~
note: provided for ‘template<class A, A value, class B> class Foo’
 class Foo {};
       ^~~
error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘validateType’
 bool validateType() {
                   ^
error: expected ‘>’ before ‘{’ token
 bool validateType() {
                     ^
```

And in the second case I get

```
error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘validateType<Foo<A, val, B> >’ is not allowed
 bool validateType<Foo<A, val, B>>() {
                                   ^
```

How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial template specializations are not allowed for function templates.
Use SFINAE or **class templates**

```
template <class T>
struct validateType : std::false_type {};

template <class A, A val, class B>
struct validateType<Foo<A, val, B>> : std::true_type {};
```

Edit:

> Is this supposed to work for template functions as well?

NO. **Partial template specializations are not allowed for function templates.**

for template function, use SFINAE.

For example, this sample check weather T is unsigned integer type(C++17).

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
T foo(T n);
```

- `std::is_unsigned_v` was added in C++17. before C++17, use `std::is_unsigned<T>::value`.
  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned
- `std::enable_if_t` was added in C++14. before C++14, use `typename std::enable_if<con, T>::type`.
  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if
- `std::nullptr_t` can hole only one value(`nullptr`) so that I use it for SFINAE enabler.
  (ja) https://qiita.com/kazatsuyu/items/203584ef4cb8b9e52462

However, in your case, you chould use class templates. It's simplest way to use class templates to check wether T is template class foo(BTW, not for template class foo, `std::is_same` is simplest way).

Comment: Is this supposed to work for template functions as well?